# httpd.config - Wamp Stopped Working?

Tags: wamp

I've been struggling with a 403 error on my WordPress site. All of the suggestions I found involved modifying the httpd.config of the apache server, particularly

(located: C:/Wamp/bin/Apache/apache2.2.22/config/httpd.conf)

```
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

to

```
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow, Deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

However this didn't work for me. I changed it back to the original settings and restarted WAMP - Now WAMP's icon goes orange instead of green.

I've seen a lot of people saying it's skype. **I do not have skype installed**. Wamp was working earlier today but it stopped after I made changes.

---

(Note, to find the httpd.config file I did a search of the folder of Apache. he first result was for a file with the same name located in: c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/conf/original/httpd.config) I mistakenly modififed this file initially but once i realised it was wrong I reverted it to it's original form).

Answer (score 0):

Point 1.
Use the wampmanager icon in the system tray, left click menus, to access config files and lots of other things. Then you will be editing the correct files.

Point 2.
What did you think the effect of

```
Deny from all
Allow from all
```

Was going to be?

#### Question:

Where did you install your wordpress site? ie what folder?

Answer (score 0):

Just back up you www directory along with your database tables, then uninstall WAMP totally. After uninstall, delete the WAMP folder. Then reinstall WAMP